# fps lag in latest version of chromium

Tags: graphics, chromium

i lately experience fps issues in an online game i play (tagpro.gg - fps dropped from 60 to ~40), but also in youtube videos (feel very chopped). this is since i updated ubuntu (14.04 lts) yesterday or so (first time in a long while), and i'm pretty sure that was the cause, since i didn't change anything else important since then.

note that those issues don't occur on arch, on which i run the latest chromium as well (which is probably a more recent version than ubuntus; i didn't bother to look up the exact version, it's the latest for each os).

how to fix?

edit: my gpu is a radeon hd4570 and i'm running the open source driver, that probably plays a role.

Answer (score 0):

That lag might be caused by an outdated Mesa driver.First tell me what version of Mesa are you running? The default one in 14.04 is Mesa 10.3.2 which is very out of date compared to the latest Mesa release.In case you are running 10.3.2 you can easily update it to 10.6.3 by installing the xorg egers ppa.In order to do so type this in the terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

After that type this in the terminal and your Mesa driver should be updated.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After that reboot and check if the latest Mesa version is installed by using Glxinfo if it's not already installed.Then just install it by this into the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

After Glxinfo is installed you can now check the Mesa version by typing this into terminal(It should say 10.6.3 now)

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

The fps lag in Chromium should now be gone If I assume correctly.